# How to create three 3D vectors which are equal angles to each other?

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, 3d, geometry, linear-algebra

I'm attempting to visualize how to manipulate three equal sized vectors so that the angle between them will be equal - similar the top of a triangular prism, or a tripod. The vectors are currently parallel to the y-axis - let's say I then rotate one 45 degrees along the x-axis from the top. How can I then rotate the others from the same point in some combination of x and z-axis rotations so that the angle between any two will be equal?

Answer (score 1):

If initial point is `(0, 1, 0)`   (vector collinear with OY, perhaps with another length instead of 1), then you can apply:

- rotation matrix by angle `Fi` (45 degrees in your case) about OX axis for all three ones
- then apply rotation matrix by 120 degrees about OY for the second one
- and apply rotation by -120 degrees about OY for the third one

Comment: and if you dont want a 360, but between 2 points you have quaternion.lerp where if you put in 0.5 it will provide the middle